# uploaded files to Azure are corrupted when using dio

Tags: azure, flutter, dart, azure-blob-storage, dio

I'm trying to upload a file from my phone to azure blob storage as a BlockBlob with a SAS. I can get the file to upload, but it can't be opened once downloaded. The file gets corrupted somehow. I thought this was a content-type problem, but I have tried several different approaches to changing to content-type. Nothing has worked so far.

My code:

```
FileInfo _fileInfo = await filePicker(); // get the file path and file name
// my getUploadInfo fires a call to my backend to get a SAS.
// I know for a fact that this works because my website uses this SAS to upload files perfectly fine
UploadInfo uploadInfo = await getUploadInfo(_fileInfo.fileName, _fileInfo.filePath); 

final bytes = File(_fileInfo.filePath).readAsBytesSync();

try {
  final response = await myDio.put(
    uploadInfo.url,
    data: bytes, 
    onSendProgress:
      (int sent, int total) {
        if (total != -1) {
          print((sent / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
        }
      },
    options:
      dioPrefix.Options(headers: {
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        'Content-Type': mime(_fileInfo.filePath),
      })
  );
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

This code uploads a file just fine. But I can't open the file since it becomes corrupted. At first, I thought this was a Content-Type problem, so I've tried changing the content type header to: `application/octet-stream` and `multipart/form-data` as well. That doesn't work.

I've also tried to do

```
dioPrefix.FormData formData =
  new dioPrefix.FormData.fromMap({
    'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
      _fileInfo.filePath,
      filename: _fileInfo.fileName,
    )
});
...
final response = await myDio.put(
    uploadInfo.url,
    data: formData, // This approach is recommended on the dio documentation
    onSendProgress:
...
```

but this also corrupts the file. It gets uploaded, but I can't open it.

I **have** been able to successfully upload a file with this code, but with this approach I cannot get any type of response so I have no idea whether it uploaded successfully or not (Also, I can't get the progress of the upload):

```
try {
  final data = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
  final response = await http.put( // here, response is empty no matter what i try to print
    url, 
    body: data, 
    headers: {
      'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
      'Content-Type': mime(filePath),
  });
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try to download the file using Azure Storage Explorer. If it's also corrupted, then it's your upload code that is broken. PS: I've never heard something like that (SAS damaging the blob content. I'm 99.999% sure it's your download / upload code)

Comment: It's also corrupted when using Azure Storage Explorer. Sorry, the title is misleading, I'll change it. I'm also 99.99999% sure it's the upload code. I'm just not sure what part of it is messing up

Comment: Unfortunately there's no SDK for flutter. You'd better try to do it using REST https://gist.github.com/gregjhogan/ef37c38371193c8e9d08d867c05ad210

PS: use a proxy to capture the request and compare with your current one, you'll be able to identify what is different

Comment: hi @wei , whenever I'm using this method im getting a 404 knowing that my url is correct and I'm unable to use a connection string with a SAS Token.. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to upload a file using [`dio`](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) in Dart to Azure Blob Storage, and then download and print the content of the file, as the code below.

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  var accountName = '<account name>';
  var containerName = '<container name>';
  var blobName = '<blob name>';
  var sasTokenContainerLevel = '<container level sas token copied from Azure Storage Explorer, such as `st=2019-12-31T07%3A17%3A31Z&se=2020-01-01T07%3A17%3A31Z&sp=racwdl&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`';
  var url = 'https://$accountName.blob.core.windows.net/$containerName/$blobName?$sasTokenContainerLevel';
  var data = File(blobName).readAsBytesSync();
  var dio = Dio();
  try {
    final response = await dio.put(
      url,
      data: data, 
      onSendProgress:
      (int sent, int total) {
        if (total != -1) {
          print((sent / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
        }
      },
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      })
    );
    print(response.data);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  Response response = await dio.get(url);
  print(response.data);
}
```

Then, I ran it and got the result as the figure below.

[image]

The content of the uploaded file as blob is the json string encoded from a `Uint8List` bytes from the funtion `readAsBytesSync`.

I researched the description and the source code of `dio`, actually I found `dio` is only suitable for sending the request body of json format, not for raw content as request body.

Fig 1. The default transformer apply for POST method

[image]

Fig 2. https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/blob/master/dio/lib/src/transformer.dart

[image]

So to fix it is to write a custom transformer class `PutTransformerForRawData` instead of the default one to override the function `transformRequest`, as the code below.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

class PutTransformerForRawData extends DefaultTransformer {
  @override
  Future<String> transformRequest(RequestOptions options) async {
    if(options.data is Uint8List) {
      return new String.fromCharCodes(options.data);
    } else if(options.data is String) {
      return options.data;
    }
  }
}
```

And to replace the default transformer via the code below.

```
var dio = Dio();
dio.transformer = PutTransformerForRawData();
```

Then, you can get the `data` via the code below.

```
var data = File(blobName).readAsBytesSync();
```

Or

```
var data = File(blobName).readAsStringSync();
```

Note: the custom transfer `PutTransformerForRawData` is only for uploading, please remove the download & print code `Response response = await dio.get(url); print(response.data);`, the default transformer seems to check the response body whether be json format, I got the exception as below when my uploaded file is my sample code.

```
Unhandled exception:
DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
import 'dart:typed_data';
```

Comment: hi @Peter I'm getting a 404 error when my url is written without a SAS Token ad a 403 error when my url is appended with a SAS Token.. any idea why? I'm sure my url is correct and the SAS is not expired.

Comment: @DCodes Did you solve the issue? I'm also getting same error when we add sas token to url 403 error

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar check this out please :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196180/unable-to-upload-to-azure-storage-with-a-sas-token-from-flutter

Comment: @DCodes thank you.. This I have checked and getting 201 as a status code.. Is it success ?

Comment: yess @MallikarjunHampannavar. A 201 status code indicates that a request was successful and as a result, a resource has been created (for example a new page)..