# Unable to upload to azure storage with a SAS Token from flutter

Tags: azure, flutter, dart, connection-string

I am attempting to upload files/data to azure storage with a SAS Token. **I was successfully able to achieve this without a SAS Token using the following method**:

> ```
>   sendToBlob (Uint8List bytes)async {
>     var storage = AzureStorage.parse('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=#;AccountKey=#==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net');
>     await storage.putBlob('/test/2.txt',bodyBytes: bytes);
>   }
> ```

When I generated a SAS Token and took the connection string with it written in the following format, **I get a parse error**:

```
"BlobEndpoint=https://#.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://#.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://#.file.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://#.table.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=sv=#"
```

**Attempting to send a put request without a connection string**, my method is as follows:

> ```
>   uploadtoAzure(String sas)async{
>     try {
>       var url = 'https://#.blob.core.windows.net/test/4.txt?'+sas;
>       Map<String, String> headers = ({"x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob"});
>       final response = await http.put(
>           url,
>           headers: headers,
>           body: 'hi'
>       );
>       print(response.statusCode);
>     } on DioError catch (e) {
>       if(e.response.statusCode == 404){
>         print(e.message);
>       }else{
>         print(e.message);
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ```

**Knowing that I'm the Owner and the Storage Blob Data Contributor of the storage account I'm uploading to and the SAS Token is not expired** ,this leads to a 403 AuthorizationPermissionMismatch error.

```
¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:bc7f5bb4-c01e-0066-0459-9a6d45000000
Time:2020-10-04T14:16:54.7302685Z</Message></Error>
```

Is there a method to upload data from flutter to azure using a connection string with a SAS Token? and how would I be able to solve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since our Azure function is generating the User Delegation SAS token, we use a registered app on Azure as a service principal.

This problem was solved by assigning **Storage Blob Data Contributor** in addition to the **Storage Blob Delegator** role to the service principal to accommodate addition of a file.