# Flutter AZURE BLOB IMAGE UPLOAD - How to upload image captured using mobile camera to azure blob storage

Tags: flutter, dart, azure-blob-storage

I have been working for few since yesterday to try upload an image to azure blob storage taken using mobile camera form iOS/Android device.

I am able to upload the files but for some reason they being corrupted not able to open the image uploaded.

Please check the image error while opening the uploaded image

[image: Valid XHTML]

I am using flutter package http with different approach all work in uploading image file to azure blob store but it gets corrupted somehow , I tried forcing the `ContentType` to `image/jpeg` but no help.

Here is code I am using an http API -

```
takePicture() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        String fileName = basename(pickedFile.path);
        uploadFile(fileName, image);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

First approach -->

```
http.Response response = await http.put(
      uri,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": 'image/jpeg',
        "X-MS-BLOB-TYPE": "BlockBlob",
      },
      body: image.path,
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
```

Using Approach second -->

```
final data = image.readAsBytesSync();
  var dio = Dio();
  dio.options.headers['x-ms-blob-type'] = 'BlockBlob';
  dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg';
  try {
    final response = await dio.put(
      '$url/$fileName?$token',
      data: data,
      onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
        if (total != -1) {
          print((sent / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
        }
      },
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

Approach third -->

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("PUT", postUri);
      request.headers['X-MS-BLOB-TYPE'] = 'BlockBlob';
      request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg';
      request.files.add(
        new http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'picture',
          await image.readAsBytes(),
        ),
      );
      request.send().then((response) {
        uploadResponse.add(response.statusCode);
      }, onError: (err) {
        print(err);
      });
```

Help here is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest using `Dio()` with the solution outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293114/uploaded-files-to-azure-are-corrupted-when-using-dio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to upload the image to Azure Blob Storage in the flutter application, you can use the Dart Package `azblob` to implement it. Regarding how to use the package, please refer to [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/azblob/latest/).

For example

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:azblob/azblob.dart';
import 'package:mime/mime.dart';

...
//use image_picker to get image

Future uploadImageToAzure(BuildContext context) async {
    try{
      String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
      // read file as Uint8List 
      Uint8List content =  await  _imageFile.readAsBytes();
      var storage = AzureStorage.parse('<storage account connection string>');
      String container="image";
      // get the mine type of the file
      String contentType= lookupMimeType(fileName);
      await storage.putBlob('/$container/$fileName',bodyBytes: content,contentType: contentType,type: BlobType.BlockBlob);
      print("done");
    } on AzureStorageException catch(ex){
      print(ex.message);
    }catch(err){
      print(err);
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is <storage account connection string> ?

Comment: @FlorianK It's a secret key to allow accessing a Azure Storage Account so you can upload the pictures. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the multipart form is causing break of image. I don't know how it works on azure side, because there is little or no information about multipart uploads, but it's clearly broken because of multipart form. I replicated the problem in .net core application and whenever i am using multipart form data to upload image - it is broken. When i am using simple ByteArrayContent - it works. I couldn't find flutter equivalent to ByteArrayContent, so i am lost now :( The package mentioned by @Jim is useless for me, because i want to give clients sas url, so they have permission to upload image on client side. I do not want to store azure storage account secrets in flutter app.

EDIT. I found the solution to send raw byte data with Dio package. You can do that also with http package.

```
final dio = new Dio();
final fileBytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
var streamData = Stream.fromIterable(fileBytes.map((e) => [e]));

await dio.put(uploadDestinationUrl,
    data: streamData,
    options: Options(headers: {
      Headers.contentLengthHeader: fileBytes.length,
      "x-ms-blob-type": "BlockBlob",
      "content-type": "image/jpeg"
    }));
```

Comment: Hi @Inclouds - so if this is a new question that relates to the answers to the original question - please create a new question, with reference to the original question and answers and what doesn't work about it - so you can get answers on it.